# Check sum total on an element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to get the checksum total of an XML file as seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<student_update date="2022-04-19" program="CA" checksum="20021682">
    <transaction>
        <program>CA</program>
        <student_no>10010823</student_no>
        <course_no>*</course_no>
        <registration_no>216</registration_no>
        <type>2</type>
        <grade>90.4</grade>
        <notes>Update Grade Test</notes>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <program>CA</program>
        <student_no>10010859</student_no>
        <course_no>M-50032</course_no>
        <registration_no>*</registration_no>
        <type>1</type>
        <grade>*</grade>
        <notes>Register Course Test</notes>
    </transaction>
</student_update>
```

I am wondering if I am going about this the right way. Please let me know:

```cs
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(inputFileName);
XElement root = xDocument.Element("student_update");
IEnumerable<XElement> studentnoElement = xDocument.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "student_no");
int checksum = studentnoElement.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.Value));
if (!root.Attribute("checksum").Value.Equals(checksum))
{
    throw new Exception(String.Format("Incorrect checksum total " + "for file {0}\n", inputFileName));
}
```

I am running into some errors with the exception is not popping up as expected. I am looking for some advice on how to correct this. Thank you!

Comment: *"I am running into some errors with the exception not popping up as expected, I am looking for some advice on how to correct this."* - what about sharing the errors? ;-)

Comment: Well there is no error to display, that is my problem. I am purposely entering an incorrect "checksum" into my XML file and the exception that I made is not popping up. @Stefan

Comment: So, what does it do then? For example: what happens if you use the debugger and inspect the parameters of the if statement? What are their values? Is there a try/catch block surrounding the throw? Is there an other exception raised which is suppressed?

Comment: No try/catch, but I realized from the answer below what my problem was. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the root element of the `checksum` attribute, you are getting the value with the `string` type.

You can check with:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(root.Attribute("checksum").Value.GetType());
```

You have to convert to `Integer` first before comparing both values.

```cs
int rootCheckSum = Convert.ToInt32(root.Attribute("checksum").Value);
if (!rootCheckSum.Equals(checksum))
{
    throw new Exception(String.Format("Incorrect checksum total " + "for file {0}\n", inputFileName));
}
```

Or prefer safely convert to Integer with `Int32.TryParse()`

```cs
int rootCheckSum = Convert.ToInt32(root.Attribute("checksum").Value);
bool isInteger = Int32.TryParse(root.Attribute("checksum").Value, out int rootCheckSum);
if (!isInteger)
{
    // Handle non-integer case
}

if (!rootCheckSum.Equals(checksum))
{
    throw new Exception(String.Format("Incorrect checksum total " + "for file {0}\n", inputFileName));
}
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sivkCZ)

Comment: Nice catch ....

Comment: Thanks so much.. didn't realize I needed to do that.